# how to set the charset of smb/cifs server on Solaris 11

Tags: character-encoding, solaris, smb

I am setup a Solaris 11 server which provides cifs/smb service since it will perform as a home NAS with ZFS. I setup the smb server and I can read/write files via smb from my Windows 7 desktop, but I found the chinese character in the file name is shown incorrect from the solaris console, how do I set the charset to get it works well?

I can copy the file with chinese character in the filename from Windows to Solaris, and vice-versa, and the chinese character is displayed well on Windows desktop, but I cannot read it in the solaris console.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the system console (/dev/console) used when no graphic environment is launched, I believe only a 7bit ASCII font is supported.

If you are under a graphic environment (Gnome or CDE), make sure you are running a UTF-8 locale.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am suing sun-color terminal, seems it does not support Chinese, maybe it supports but I don't find the way.The locale is zh.UTF8, I tried using PuTTY to connect my solaris server with UTF8, it works well.

Comment: `sun-color` is precisely the system console and it doesn't indeed support anything non 7 bit ASCII. What server model are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

The locale is zh.UTF8, I tried using PuTTY to connect my solaris server with UTF8, it works well.